# Using Scala object in Java

Tags: java, scala, rabbitmq

I am using a Reactive RabbitMQ library which is written in Scala.

I came across this construct:

```
public interface DeliveryMode { }

public final class Persistent {
    public static String toString() {
        return Persistent$.MODULE$.toString();
    }

    // Other static functions.
}

public final class Persistent$ implements DeliveryMode, Product, Serializable {
    public static final Persistent$ MODULE$;

    static {
        new Persistent$();
    }

    // Other code
    public String toString() {
        return "Persistent";
    }

    private Persistent$() {
        MODULE$ = this;
        class.$init$(this);
    }
}
```

If they want to access a Function that accepts `DeliveryMode`
like

```
public Message(DeliveryMode mode) {}
```

They simply pass in Scala

```
Message(Persistent);
```

Can this type be used in Java too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is in java so I don't see where the confusion is.  Of course it works from java just as you expect.  The class Persistent$ implements DeliveryMode has a static instance of itself called MODULE$.

```
Message(Persistent$.MODULE$);
```

Assuming Persistent$ is properly imported.

Comment: I think OP might be confused with the `$`? It is a legal character for class and variable names.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are showing is in Java. Scala and Java are generally interoperable, if you keep in mind which Scala concepts map to which Java concepts. So the answer is yes, you can use the Scala objects from Java.

See for instance

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html

http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~michelou/scala/using-scala-from-java.html